# CSS @import and the order of it

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use @import in **one** css file like this.

```
@import file1
some css here
@import file2
```

chrome doesn't recognize the second import for the above but this will work

```
@import file1
@import file2
some css here
```

The problem here is I need "some css" to be in the middle because file2 will override some of them. Is there any other solution other than importing 3 files from html?

Comment: You assume @import will process files in a particular order... it may not.  http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is not possible:

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#at-import:

> The '@import' rule allows users to import style rules from other style sheets. In CSS 2.1, any @import rules must precede all other rules (except the @charset rule, if present).

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#at-rules:

> Assume, for example, that a CSS 2.1 parser encounters this style
>   sheet:
>
> ```
> @import "subs.css";
> h1 { color: blue }
> @import "list.css";
> ```
>
> The second '@import' is illegal according to CSS 2.1. The CSS 2.1
>   parser ignores the whole at-rule, effectively reducing the style sheet
>   to:
>
> ```
> @import "subs.css";
> h1 { color: blue }
> ```

---

There is no need to define the rules between the `@import`s though. If you want to override properties in file 1, they can also be added *after* the `@import` blocks. Properties which are overridden in file 2 can be omitted.

Comment: Yes you are right but it's very confusing. There's @media and stuff which I'm very confuse at. I got two files from twitter bootstrap, one is called Bootstrap and the other is Bootstrap-responsive. I need to add `body {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
};` in the middle and I can't omit anything in this. Or else it will not work.

Comment: @JonathanShepherd Who says that you **have to** put the CSS between it? If there's no definition of `body {padding-top: ...; padding-bottom: ..;}` or `padding:` in the second CSS file, you can safely put it after the second `@import` rule.

Comment: There's one `@media (max-width: 980px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0;
  } ......` Now there's a huge problem, If I remove my **some css** the text will not get padded at the top. Which result in the nav-bar at the top overriding my content. If I add **some css** after bootstrap-responsive then the mobile view will get the wrong padding at the top(it pad the nav-bar not the content).

Comment: here's three situation that I can get into. To clear what I have said above.
1. boot > code > respon = Perfect. Both desktop and mobile.
2. boot > respon = Content not padded, nav-bar override.
3. boot > respon > code = Perfect for desktop view. It adds padding at the top of the nav-bar AND the content in mobile view.

If you need some test code I will add them.

Comment: @JonathanShepherd The only thing I can think of requires one additional tag: http://pastebin.com/VBD5Vcu1

Comment: I found a solution, the only way to do it is to include all 3 css file  to one file only by hand. and import it. I will mark your answer to correct but for other looking for this solution, look at this comment. Ty.

Comment: @JonathanShepherd please see my answer to a possible (and easier to maintain) solution

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos that's why I remove it and combile all of them by hand).

Answer (score 5):

As others said, this is invalid CSS, but I want to add my 2 cents. If you are looking for a way to overcome this problem and also write *better* CSS (ie CSS that is more concise, easier to read and to maintain), you can use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). It's a program that enhances the CSS syntax and generates valid CSS files ready to be served to browsers. It's installed as a Ruby gem, then you can launch it this way

```
sass --watch  style.scss:style.css
```

Every time `style.scss` is modified, a new `style.css` is compiled. `scss` is the standard file extensions for SASS source files. In SASS this code is valid

```
@import "import1.scss";

a {
  color: red;
}

@import "import2.scss";
```

and compiles to the following `style.css`

```
a {
  /* This is the content of import1.scss */
  color: white;
}
a {
  color: red;
}
a {
  /* This is the content of import2.scss */
  color: white;
}
```

Note that I imported files ending in **scss**. This is advertised by [the SASS reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) not to fall back to regular CSS imports.

Comment: Seem like a very good nice solution but I'm already using LESS for the client-side. From what I read sass is on the server-side and should work with LESS. I will take a look at this. Thanks @Raddaele

Comment: upvoted, you practically saying that i can import other css file inside of my current css module in any where i wanted ????

Answer (score 1):

This is odd, but CSSWG intentionally disallows `@import` after property rules.

They [say](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jan/0932.html):

> Flexibility includes the Working Group's ability to assign some
>   meaning to @import after a certain point in a style sheet in the
>   future without the new behavior being in conflict with existing
>   practise in certain ways. You could read the current requirements as
>   saying that using the @import rule at certain points as something the
>   Working Group reserves for later use when it finds a usage that is
>   more valuable to authors than being able to use it with the usual
>   meaning right now. Assinging a specific meaning to it now would
>   probably remove that option, so this may be a loss in the long term.

Also they say that @import itself descreases downloading speed (that's weak argument though, since it then does not matter where @import is placed — before property rules or after them, but former *is* allowed).

So we are forced to use a workaround like using one "TOC" stylesheet that only contains @imports in desired order (but that increments number of files that browser needs to download).

Comment: to be honest speed really doesn't matter. Both of my test case works fine in product time after minified. The minified engine works fine with both type of import. The problem is on development and how to build script which I can't change works. It works by minifying all css in "style.css" only which I have to use import to get other css. So my solution right now is to combine all of them by hand, which works nicely.

Answer (score -4):

Use `!important` to prevent overriding

Something like this

```
<style>
.el{color:red !important;}
.el{color:blue;}
</style>
```

The color will stay red